# Testing my OpenGL ES 3.2 application without a virtual device?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, opengl-es

I have an Android application that runs entirely through these two functions:

```
extern "C"
{
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_android_gl2jni_GL2JNILib_init(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj,  jint width, jint height);
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_android_gl2jni_GL2JNILib_step(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj);
};

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_android_gl2jni_GL2JNILib_init(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj,  jint width, jint height)
{
    setupGraphics(width, height);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_android_gl2jni_GL2JNILib_step(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{
    renderFrame();
}
```

and it's up to me to implement what `setupGraphics` and `renderFrame` do.

My PC gets really slow with Android Studio, as soon as the virtual device is on. I would like, first, to test my application directly as a C++ program, without the need of a target device. This way, I could fix whatever needs to be fixed, and when I think everything works, I can test it again on the target device.

Problem: I don't know how to create a rendering loop in C++ with the OpenGL ES 3.2 library. Is that possible? Or am I doomed to always test my OpenGL ES 3.2 code with a virtual device?

Answer (score 0):

I've used [PVRVFrame](https://www.imgtec.com/developers/powervr-sdk-tools/pvrvframe/) to add OpenGLES codepaths to my games' Windows builds. I've only gone as far as 3.0 but I assume 3.2 support is adequate. I find performance under GLES is noticeably poorer than under DX11 or Vulkan codepaths, but our relatively demanding (for mobile) games are still playable on mid-level PCs.

[This](https://www.saschawillems.de/blog/2015/04/19/using-opengl-es-on-windows-desktops-via-egl/) tutorial is a little old now, but may be useful - it mentions some other options for running GLES on Windows (I've only ever tried PVRVFrame so I don't know how it compares).